# How to get actual invocation count of a optimized function in V8

Tags: javascript, v8

Every function has a property `invocation_count` in FeedbackVector to record the number of times the function was called. But after a function is optimized, its invocation count will not be increased when I call this function again. Is there any way to get the invocation count or update the invocation count attribute in FeedbackVector after a function has been optimized?

Comment: Can you help me? Thank you for your answer! @jmrk

Comment: What would you use this for? The purpose of `invocation_count` is optimisation only, and once optimised the `FeedbackVector` does no longer need to be updated.

Comment: It sounds like what you actually want is to use a profiler, not some v8 engine implementation details.

Comment: Yes! Actually I want to do some research about `deoptimization` in some real web pages, such as how ofter does it occur, or how many times an optimized function will bailout after execution. @Bergi

Answer (score 2):

(V8 developer here.)

No, there isn't. Optimized functions don't count how often they've been called (because they have no reason to; having them update a counter would be a waste of time).

If you really care, you have two options:

(1) You could add counters in the JavaScript source of the function(s) in question:

```js
var myFuncCalled = 0;
function myFunc() {
  myFuncCalled++;
  // rest of the function's code...
}
```

And dump those counters at the end of the program.

(2) You could modify V8 to make optimized code update the count in the feedback vector. Off the top of my head I'm not sure how exactly you'd do that, but it's certainly possible. (We wouldn't want to upstream such a patch, this would be just for your local experimentation.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have a preliminary idea. If I want to know the invocation count of an optimized function `func`, the parent function which calls `func` is `p_func`,
(1) if `p_func` hasn't been JITed, I can update the invocation count of `func` in the `Call` bytecode handler. (Can I?)  (2) if `p_func` has been JITed, now I can't find the entry to update the invocation count of `func`, could you give me some advice about the above situation?

Comment: I know that optimized functions still have access to their feedback vector (see e.g. uses of `CollectFeedbackInGenericLowering`), but I'm not familiar with the details of how that currently works. It should therefore be possible to make optimized functions update their own call count, but I don't have time to look into it more deeply.